# Bash Script Conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm building a bash script to send an email based off the last command. I seem to be having difficulties. Outside of a script the command works fine but when putting it in script it doesn't give the desired outcome.

Here is snippet of script:

```
grep -vFxf /path/to/first/file /path/to/second/file > /path/to/output/file.txt 
if [ -s file.txt ] || echo "file is empty";
then
          swaks -t "1@email.com" -f "norply@email.com" --header "Subject: sample" --body "Empty"
else
          swaks -t "1@email.com" -f "norply@email.com" --header "subject: sample" --body "Not Empty"
fi
```

I ran the commands outside of script and I can see that there is data but when I add the commands within script I get the empty output. Please advise . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Are `[ -s file.txt ]` and `/path/to/output/file.txt` the same? (you should always double-quote within `[...]` -- granted with `file.txt` it makes no difference, but if it is a variable - double-quote) Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, those two files are the same . Thanks, I'll update with the double quotes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition will always be true, because if `[ -s file.txt ]` fails, the exit status of the `||`-list is the exit status of `echo`, which is almost guaranteed to be 0. You want to move the `echo` out of the condition and into the body of the `if` statement. (And to simplify further, just set the body to a variable and call `swaks` after the `if` completes.

```
if [ -s file.txt ];
then
    body="Not Empty"
else
    echo "file is empty"
    body="Empty"
fi
swaks -t "1@email.com" -f "norply@email.com" --header "subject: sample" --body "$body"
```

---

If the only reason you create `file.txt` is to check if it is empty or not, you can just put the `grep` command directly in the `if` condition:

```
if grep -vFxfq /atph/to/first/file /path/to/second/file; then
    body="Not Empty"
else
    echo "No output"
    body="Empty"
fi

swaks -t "1@email.com" -f "norply@email.com" --header "subject: sample" --body "$body"
```